# How do I set include paths when not using an IDE so it isn't cumbersome

Tags: c, makefile, path, preprocessor

I've been trying to work without an IDE. Now I'm setting up a project that I had done
on stm32cubeIDE. I got to the point where I'm adding headers and such to the main.c file. In the IDE I was able to tell the IDE where to look for headers, like the driver folder or w/e I called it. Without IDE, I had to go and change the path in the #include statement such that

```
#include "cooldriver.h"
```

became

```
#include "driver/cooldriver.h"
```

Then,I also have to change cooldriver.c's path to point to the right path.
Is there a way to simplify this so I don't have to go through and change all the #includes and just keep what I had.
I'm working in linux env and using arm-none-eabi-gcc.
The path i have is like,

- main.c
- Makefile
- drivers

  - Inc

    - driver1.h
    - driver2.h
  - Src

    - driver1.c
    - driver2.c

TLTR: I want to tell compiler where to look for header files without an ide and without rewriting all the include statements.
Thanks.

Comment: Use the `-I` (upper-case i) option to add a path to be searched? This is well-documented.

Comment: How do you build your project?

Comment: Note that some projects design their headers to require the `"subdir/header.h"` notation.  What should be used with the `-I` option (referenced by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965371/how-do-i-set-include-paths-when-not-using-an-ide-so-it-isnt-cumbersome#comment130598977_73965371) depends in part on the current directory when running the compilation and also on where the source file is located.  But fixing the `makefile` is generally fairly easy.

Comment: Do you have an inconsistency between the file hierarch (which has a subdirectory `drivers`) and the modified include file (which uses a subdirectory `driver`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TLTR: I want to tell compiler where to look for header files without an ide and without rewriting all the include statements.

Among their many available command-line options, compilers accept some that tell them about paths to search for headers and external libraries.  On UNIX-heritage systems, the traditional one for paths that `#include` should consider is `-I`.  Your compiler's documentation will provide more detail.

The traditional approach would be to set one or more variables in your makefile to contain the wanted command-line flags, and to expand those variables where appropriate in your `make` recipes.  Sticking with convention, I would use variable `CPPFLAGS` for `-I` and other flags directed toward the C preprocessor.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. It makes sense that gcc has such a command. Next time I have a question like this I'll have to look through its commands list, or at least I'll be better equipped to word it better for a google search. Thanks.